# How to NOT convert uppercase to lowercase after using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I want to highlight the matching words in a searchbar , and here's the code :

```js
export default function App() {
  const keyword = "abc";
  const originStre = "ABCab aba abc ccc babccc";
  let re = new RegExp(keyword, "gi");
  let title = originStre.replace(re, `<span class="keyword">${keyword}</span>`);
  console.log("title", title);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <li
        style={{ textAlign: "left", padding: "8px 0 0 8px" }}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: title }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here is the online demo : https://codesandbox.io/embed/highlight-words-x1gcm?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

the problem is, it transfers 'ABCab aba abc ccc babccc' to 'abcab ...' after regex. How can I keep the original case of the letter?

Comment: `.replace(re, '<span class="keyword">$&</span>')`

Comment: that looks a lot like javascript, but ```return (
<div>
);
```  is not valid javascript syntax

Comment: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537)

Comment: @hanshenrik : that's JSX syntax for React component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you replace, you need to replace with actual match, not keyword:

```
let title = originStre.replace(re, m => `<span class="keyword">${m}</span>`)
```